# How can I set universal value of the attribute android:layoutDirection on Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, arabic, right-to-left

How can I set universal value of the attribute `android:layoutDirection` on Android? So, I'd be able to use different values for different locales.

I tried the following (using `strings.xml` for the last two lines):

```
android:layoutDirection="@string/autortl"

<string name="autortl" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">ltr</string> // main locale

<string name="autortl">rtl</string> // for RTL locales
```

But it doesn't work with the run-time error: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #381: Binary XML file line #381: Error inflating class <unknown>`

Comment: Dimens also don't work with the error: `error: invalid dimen.`

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine (use `integers.xml` for the last two lines):

```
android:layoutDirection="@integer/autortl"

<integer name="autortl">0</integer> // main locale

<integer name="autortl">1</integer> // for RTL locales
```

Answer (score 0):

Better answer - just use the following code instead:

```
android:layoutDirection="locale"
```